# How to set an appropriate point of view?

Tags: matplotlib

How to set xlim and ylim to see both cureves (omega and y) on a plot? Or how to verify that it is not possible?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

e = 1.602176634e-19
m_e = 9.1093837015e-31
k = np.arange(0.00001, 50000, 0.003)
eps_0 = 8.8541878128e-12
n_0 = 100
c = 299792458
omega_p = np.sqrt(n_0*e**2/(eps_0*m_e))           
omega = np.sqrt(omega_p**2+c**2+k**2)

y = k*c

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [5, 5]

# Plot
ax.yaxis.set_label_coords(-0.07, 0.84)
ax.xaxis.set_label_coords(0.95, -0.05)
ax.set_xlabel(r'$k$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$\omega$', rotation='horizontal')
ax.set_xlim(10000, 40000)
ax.set_ylim(299792454, 299792462.1700816)
ax.plot(k, omega)
ax.plot(k, y)

# Focusing on appropriate part
print(omega[1000000]-omega[999999])
print(omega[-1]-omega[-2])
print(len(omega))
print(k[1000000])
print(k[-1])
print(omega[1000000])
print(omega[-1])
print(y[int(ax.get_xlim()[0])])
print(y[int(ax.get_xlim()[1])])
plt.show()
```

The output now:

[image]

There should be also an assymptote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An idea is to just let matplotlib choose its default limits. Then you can interactively zoom in to an area of interest. The code below sets a log scale for the y-axis, which might help to fit everything. In order to avoid too many points, the 16 million points of `np.arange(0.00001, 50000, 0.003)` are replaced by `np.linspace(0.00001, 50000, 10000)`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

e = 1.602176634e-19
m_e = 9.1093837015e-31
# k = np.arange(0.00001, 50000, 0.003)
k = np.linspace(0.00001, 50000, 10000)
eps_0 = 8.8541878128e-12
n_0 = 100
c = 299792458
omega_p = np.sqrt(n_0 * e ** 2 / (eps_0 * m_e))
omega = np.sqrt(omega_p ** 2 + c ** 2 + k ** 2)

y = k * c

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [5, 5]

ax.set_xlabel(r'$k$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$\omega$', rotation='horizontal')
ax.plot(k, omega, color='blue')
ax.plot(k, y, color='red')
ax.set_yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]